# Given a link with a location "loc" search extract latitude and longitude from marker using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Say I have a given a link to a [map with a location marker](https://maps.google.com/?q=loc%3a%202526%20Mathews%20Street%20Berkeley%20CA%20US) , how can I find the latitude and longitude from that map marker using JavaScript and the Google API?

The trick is that I don't know the address. Is there a way to find out what the address on the page is elegantly, without having to use regular expressions on the HTML?

Specifically, I want to extract the address and latitude/longitude out of the given marker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 'easy'. Google Maps api has a geolocation object, that is the same used by google maps. So you should use something like that:

```
var geocodeLocation = 'String of the adress you''re looking for';

  var geocoder = new google.maps.ClientGeocoder();
  geocoder.getLatLng(geocodeLocation, function(point) {
    if (point) {
      //Do something with point - //You have point.x and point.y
    }
  });
```

Comment: The trick is that I don't know the address.  Is there a way to find out what the address on the page is elegantly, without having to use regular expressions on the HTML?

Comment: But you already had the address on your URL, so the only thing that was missing is to geocode the location using what I said.

Comment: Yes, I realize now that the address was in the URL, which is easy to extract using regex.  I didn't realize that Google passes map links so nicely. So my question was much easier than I realized.  Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the Google Maps API you can just use the geocoding web service directly and get a response in [**JSON**](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=2526%20Mathews%20Street,Berkeley,CA,US) or [**XML**](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=2526%20Mathews%20Street,Berkeley,CA,US)

[**Documentation here**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of finding the address given the URL is actually way easier than I thought.  In my case, the Google Maps URLs I am given are of the form:

https://maps.google.com/?q=loc:+ADDRESS+CITY+STATE+COUNTRY

So, I quickly get the address from the URL directly.
I don't know if that's the default for google maps URLS. If not, then things would be more difficult.

From here, it's a simple use of the geocoder, of which there are plenty of examples on the [Google Maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/).